# Is there a LLVM Matcher for any conditional?

Tags: clang-ast-matchers

Is there a LLVM AST matcher for the use of a C conditional? I know there is the hasCondition() option for ifStmt, but that is only good for an if statement. In particular, I'm looking to match for a boolean condition that has no operator (e.g. `if (flag)`, `while(flag)`, or `(flag ? x : y)`). But I'd also be interested in the more generic case of any conditional.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find was for ifStmt, whileStmt or doStmt:
xxxStmt(unless(hasCondition(binaryOperator(isComparisonOperator()))))
which allows me to also check for things like `if (!flag)`

For the case `flag ? x : y`, one can match conditionalOperator() then determine if the expression has a comparison operator.